# Android how to get user Facebook information when user is already logged in

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

How can I get users facebook information when he is already logged in? I think I am doing everything fine but its not working..

1st. I am getting the accessToken and checking if it exists. If it does exist I try to get user data.

```
AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();

   if (accessToken != null) {

      String userData = getUserDataFromFacebook(accessToken, headerTitle);

      headerTitle.setText(userData);
   }
```

2nd. I try to get the user data the same way as i would get it at the first facebook login.

```
getUserDataFromFacebook:

    private String getUserDataFromFacebook(AccessToken accessToken, final TextView headerTitle) {

Log.v("LoginActivity", "I am here");  // this log works

        GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                accessToken,
                new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {

                        Log.v("LoginActivity", "RESPONSE: " + response); //this log doesn`t work.

                        // Application code
                        try {
                             Log.v("LoginActivity", "I am here"); //this log doesn`t work
                             name = object.getString("name");

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                });

        return name;

    }
```

The biggest problem is that the the onCompleted method is not called and I cant access any of the information. I have no idea why..

P.S. I am terrible at Java and this is my first android application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually executing the request.

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        accessToken,
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(
                   JSONObject object,
                   GraphResponse response) {
                // your logic
            }
        });
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link");
request.setParameters(parameters);
request.executeAsync();
```

Keep in mind this is an Async call so you can't return the name from the function like you've tried to do. Instead you'll have to implement a callback mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code as it is it will help you to get data from facebook.
make sure you already set permission for data on FacebookLoginButton.

```
private void getUserDataFromFacebook() {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                            Log.e(" Response", response.toString());
                            String res = (String) object.toString();
                            Log.e("Response", res);
                            Gson gson = new Gson();
                            if (res.length() > 0) {

                               //do your work here with your res

                            } else {
                                Utils.showDialog(SelectFacebookAlbumActivity.this, "",
                                        "Error in getting data");
                            }

                        }
                    });

            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();
        }
```

Let us know it it works for you.